# Is it true $\sqrt{2^{3^{-5^{-7^{11^{13^{-17^{-19^{23^{29^{-31^{-37^{41^{\ldots}}}}}}}}}}}}}} =\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, radicals

> ***Question:*** Is it true and easy to show that:
>
> $$\sqrt{2^{3^{-5^{-7^{11^{13^{-17^{-19^{23^{29^{-31^{-37^{41^{\ldots}}}}}}}}}}}}}} =\sqrt{2}$$ ?

Implicitly I am making the claim $2^{3^{-5^{-7^{11^{13^{-17^{-19^{23^{29^{-31^{-37^{41^{\ldots}}}}}}}}}}}}} =2$. Computationally it has been verified up to the [prime exponent 41](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%5B2%5E3%5E-5%5E-7%5E11%5E13%5E-17%5E-19%5E23%5E29%5E-31%5E-37%5E41%5D). I do not have a computing platform to handle additional exponents. Note it is not an alternating sequence of $+/-$. But rather the parity in the prime exponents reads starting at the exponent $3$: $+,-,-,+,+,-,-,+,+,-,-,\ldots$. I have no reason to believe it is true on the other hand I do not believe it coincidence.

***Background and motivation:*** I was looking for "easy", possibly trivial, expression in order to rewrite the $\sqrt{2}.$ For example it is apparently [easy to show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533636/convergence-of-alternating-nested-radicals) that $\sqrt{\sqrt{3-\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3-\sqrt{3+\ldots}}}}}=\sqrt{2}.$ So, I began "playing" with other expression in Wolfram Alpha and came up with this question.  In order to convince yourself just consider typing $\text{sqrt(2^3^-5^-7^11^13^-17^-19^23^-29^-31^37)}$ into the google search bar. I was worried this was obvious but I cannot seem to figure it out. I don't think it is computational junk from Wolfram or Google.

Comment: Why do you need the outer square root?

Comment: ^ Did I make a typo ? I was looking for ways to rewrite the square root of two. So the outer square root is necessary ?

Comment: But if you remove the sqrt on both sides, the equality won't be endangered.

Comment: PARI/GP can only calculate this expression upto $-7$. The value is very near $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: What you need is to prove that the exponent tend to $1$. And $3^{f(x)}$ tends to $1$ for all $f$ tending to $0$.

Comment: Your question seems to mean mostly "what I'm talking about?", I can't answer it. As you wrote it, with that haphazard combination of positive and negative exponents, it may mean anything, so it means nothing. Rewrite it in some mathematically meaningful sense, pease.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez But To show this limit you have to handle another power tower with a difficult-to-handle sign-pattern. Not sure whether this leads to anywhere.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez Since power towers usually are solved from above, the expression is well-defined (if we assume this convention). But the limit of the power tower is far from trivial, nevertheless I think it is actually $2$.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez The approach is good, but because of the many minus-signs, I am not sure whether it actually works.

Comment: @Peter. *"Since power towers usually are solved from above, the expression is well-defined"* - This is not true in general, and definitely not a proof that this expression defines exactly one real number.

Comment: @ThePirateBay The limit might not exist, but if we truncate at some point, we always have a well defined power tower. But you are right in the sense that the expression is only valid if it has a limit.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez Do you actually need this sign-pattern ? If you take $-5$ and all the other primes with positive sign, the limit becomes almost trivial.

Comment: The question is written as is. Do I need the $+,+,-,-$ pattern in the prime exponents to achieve the number 2, possibly not. I took for granted the tower was well-defined and converges.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convergence of your tower to $2$ is equivalent to convergence of $3^{-5^{-7^{11^\ldots}}}$ to $1$, which is equivalent to convergence of $5^{-7^{11^{13^\ldots}}}$ to $0$, which is equivalent to convergence of $7^{11^{13^{-17^\ldots}}}$ to $\infty$, which is equivalent to convergence of $11^{13^{-17^{-19^\ldots}}}$ to $\infty$, which is equivalent to convergence of $13^{-17^{-19^{23^\ldots}}}$ to $\infty$, which is equivalent to convergence of $17^{-19^{23^{29^\ldots}}}$ to $-\infty$, which is absurd.

Comment: So you want to say that this power tower has no limit ? I am not convinced of the argument of the alternating limits. We have basically the same problem with the rest power towers as with the whole power tower.

Comment: Apart from the fact that this answer tends to be funny, it doesn't answer the main problem: does this limit converge to exactly one real number? If yes, can we find it, if no, can we prove it?

Comment: In fact the given power tower seems to be "pathological"

Comment: @Peter what do you mean by pathological ?

Comment: "Difficult to handle"

Comment: @ThePirateBay The question was not if thelimit exists, but if the limit equals $2$

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to Hagen von Eitzen's answer. If we truncate the power tower at any point past $29$, then we have the following inequalities:

\begin{align*}
1 &\le 23^{29^\cdots}
\\
19 &\le 19^{23^\cdots}
\\
0 &\le 17^{-19^\cdots}\le 17^{-19}
\\
13^{-17^{-19}} &\le 13^{-17^\cdots} \le 1
\\
11^{13^{-17^{-19}}} &\le 11^{13^\cdots} \le 11
\\
7^{11^{13^{-17^{-19}}}} &\le 7^{11^\cdots} \le 7^{11}
\\
5^{-7^{11}} &\le 5^{-7^\cdots} \le 5^{-7^{11^{13^{-17^{-19}}}}}
\\
3^{-5^{-7^{11^{13^{-17^{-19}}}}}} &\le 3^{-5^\cdots} \le 3^{-5^{-7^{11}}}
\\
2^{3^{-5^{-7^{11^{13^{-17^{-19}}}}}}} &\le 2^{3^\cdots} \le 2^{3^{-5^{-7^{11}}}}
\end{align*}

You can check that $2^{3^{-5^{-7^{11}}}} < 2$, so it is impossible for the power tower to converge to $2$, but the partial towers are extremely close to $2$. You can check that both $\log_{10}\left(2-2^{3^{-5^{-7^{11^{13^{-17^{-19}}}}}}}\right)$ and $\log_{10}\left(2-2^{3^{-5^{-7^{11}}}}\right)$ are very roughly $-1.382 \times 10^9$.